# sorry, we couldn't find ABC.xism'. is it possible it was moved or deleted?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, prompt

I have two files:

- Listing Database Sheet PRO version quick - SCRAP3.xism
- Copy of Listing Database Sheet PRO version quick - SCRAP - testing the script PRO19

Both are on my OneDrive folder.

As I don't need the SCRAP3 file, I want to move it to a folder I called "old versions" that is *not* on the OneDrive, but on my C drive.

After I moved it, any time I try to open:

Copy of Listing Database Sheet PRO version quick - SCRAP - testing the script PRO19

... this error message pops up:

> sorry, we couldn't find 'https://d.docs.live.net/dc01971bce3b143a/Buisiness/Listings Folders/2018-2019/Listing Database Sheet PRO version quick - SCRAP3.xlsm'.  is it possible it was moved or deleted?

Then if I click OK a second one does pop up... I click OK then the file works as expected without any issues whatsoever.

How can I know if they are linked in some way?

Although the file opens and works properly I just want to know what causes the prompt and how to have it solved.

Comment: What happens when you shorten the name of the file and the path?

Comment: What I mean is first change the name from `Copy of Listing Database Sheet PRO version quick - SCRAP - testing the script PRO19` to `LDS_PRO.xlsm`. This might solve the issue. If it doesn't then copy that file to a shorter path and try again?

Comment: @SiddharthRout That path is just 171 characters, well within the limits. I guess it's the i vs l that is the problem

Comment: The "I" was a typo. it in fact is xLsm

Comment: Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54279293/edit) to reflect that? Otherwise, someone more zealous than me might vote to close it as a typo. It would probably also help to include the code you're using to copy the files.

Comment: Done. I changed it.

Comment: @teylyn: As I guessed it, the "i" was a typo. Some times even if the path/file name is within limits, onedrive has shown that weird behaviour with long name files... It was a shot i n the dark. Not sure if it helped OP as he has not responded to my suggestion...

Comment: @SiddharthRout the suggestion has not worked.

Comment: Did you try both? Try downloading the file on the desktop and open it. Does it still give you the message after downloading?